# Using functions to make loops

Tags: functional-style

I'm trying to make a simulation of an electron that goes through a magnetic and electric field perpendicular to each other and to the velocity of the electron but I'm running in some troubles with the *Mathematica* language. I'm a beginner at *Mathematica* language and I ended up probably using too much procedural programming and I would like suggestions on how I can improve it using real *Mathematica* language. For those who saw this question before I edited it, the second problem was fixed and it was a simple logic mistake, so I took it of the question.

```
vel = {0.05*300000000, 0, 0}; (* velocity *)
pos = {0, 0, 0}; (* position *)
acel = {0, 0, 0}; (* acceleration *)
ce = {0, -5000, 0}; (* electric field *)
cm = {0, 0, -0.0003}; (* magnetic field *)
dt = 0.000000000001;
l = 0.05; (* length of the region where there are magnetic and electric fields *)
me = 9.10938*10^-31; (* electrons mass *)
q = -1.60217657*10^-19; (* elementary charge *)
data = Table[0, {i, 1000000}, {j, 2}];
For[count = 1, pos[[1]] <= 1.5*l, count++,
     If[Abs[pos[[1]]] <= l, acel = q/me*(ce + (vel\[Cross]cm)), acel = {0, 0, 0}]; 
     pos = pos + vel*dt + (acel*dt^2)/2; vel = vel + acel*dt;
     data[[count, 1]] = pos[[1]]; data[[count, 2]] = pos[[2]]
   ];
For[r = 100000; s = 0.00001, r > 0.001, r = (r/10); s = (s/10),
     While[Abs[vel[[2]]] > r, cm[[3]] = cm[[3]] - s; 
             vel = {0.05*300000000, 0, 0}; 
             pos = {0, 0, 0}; 
             data = Table[0, {i, 1000000}, {j, 2}];
                 For[count = 1, pos[[1]] <= 1.5*l, count++,
                      If[Abs[pos[[1]]] <= l, acel = q/me*(ce + (vel\[Cross]cm)), acel = {0, 0, 0}]; 
                      pos = pos + vel*dt + (acel*dt^2)/2; vel = vel + acel*dt;
                      data[[count, 1]] = pos[[1]]; data[[count, 2]] = pos[[2]]
                    ];
          ];
    ];
```

I know that there are duplicate variable declarations and redundant statements in the code, its because I pasted everything together to post here, but it was originally apart.

Comment: Please post code, not images of code, and make sure that code evaluates properly in a fresh kernel session.

Comment: I can't even read the tiny text in your code image. Please post your code with proper markdown formatting.

Comment: So what if I do? Do you expect me, then, to manually retype all your code into _Mathematica_ so I can work with it? No way.

Comment: Markdown and formatting help: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting

Comment: Most users will only bite if code is posted here, which is sensible, too.

Comment: Don't try to run the whole thing at once. For instance, if you have `r` go from 1 to 0.01 (Instead of from 100000 to 0.001) you can get an error message in a few seconds. The error shows that the value of `count`, which indexes into `data`, can go above 100000, the size of data. So the logic of your stopping criteria is flawed.

Comment: @bills thanks for noticing that! After taking a look at the code again with that in mind I realized I wasn't making the steps smaller, but bigger. I'm editing my question now to make it better and exclude that particular issue.

Comment: @Yves Klett I edited the question, is it ok now?

Comment: Cannot tell, I usually cannot be bothered to debug long, uncommented code. It may be o.k., but not attractive, as questions go.

Comment: @YvesKlett ok, thank you for the feedback. I'll not add comments or anything since I got a nice answer, but I will on future questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I adapted a very primitive procedure I wrote to mimick the computation of the orbit of Saturn as seen on volume 1 of the Feynman's Lectures on Physics.
Let's define the constants:

```
me = 9.10938*10^-31;
q = -1.60217657*10^-19;
```

The state of the system at a given time is described by the vectors position (`r`) and mom--- velocity (`v`). The state of the system a quid `dt` after that time is given by:

> ```
> nextStep[dt_][{r0_, v0_}] :=
>     Block[{a, v, r},
>       a = q/me(Ef + Cross[v0, Bf]);
>       v = v0 + a dt;
>       r = r0 + v dt;
>       {r, v}
>       ];
> ```

(Two caveats, here: This is not the smartest way to compute `a`, `v` and `r`. I also have a version that follows Feynman's advice to make it a but smarter but I do not want to spoil your fun. Also, you'll have to add the condition in the computation of `a`. Something like `a = If[ Abs[r0[[1]]]<1, that 'a' there, else 0]`.) **EDIT**: You might also want to impose similar conditions on the fields, in which case you will have to make them a function of position, so that a will use Ef[r0] and Bf[r0].

Let's write a procedure that computes all the steps you want. Since I totally lack fantasy, I will call it "compute".

> ```
> compute[r0_, v0_, dt_, n_Integer] := NestList[nextStep[dt], {r0, v0}, n]
> ```

(`NestList` and `Nest` are function you want to learn).
Let's compute a few values, shall we?

```
Ef = {0, -5000, 0}; Bf = {0, 0, -0.0003};
compute[{0, 0, 0}, {0.05*3 10^8, 0, 0}, 0.000000000001, 5]
```

you get a list in the form

```
{{r0,v0},{r1,v1},...,{r5,v5}}
```

From which you can extract the trajectory. For Feynman's example I had written a procedure to do just that (but I used only scalars, so since it is easy to write one, I won't bother you with that).

Oh, in case you are wondering what was that Feynman suggested to increase the precision of the computation, well...
Look it up on the Lectures: Book I, Chapter 9, Psalm 7: Planetary Motion.